# RCaller not available in Maven version of R3.2.2 and below

Tags: java, rjava, rcaller

I am using RCaller to execute my R commands within java

```
        Caller caller = new RCaller();
        RCode code = new RCode();
        caller.setRscriptExecutable("C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.2.2\\bin\\Rscript");
        caller.cleanRCode();            
        String command = "XYZ R ccommand";
        code.addRCode(command);
        caller.setRCode(code);  
        caller.runAndReturnResult("b"); //This should output the value of b
```

caller.setRCode(code);  is where it gives error, eclipse suggests addRcode, while doing so, again error.

I am using R3.2.2 ON win7 64x

On git https://github.com/jbytecode/rcaller/blob/master/RCaller/src/main/java/examples/Example2.java this method is defined but throws error on the same cmd line.

Comment: I tried your code and it works. try using the new version of the rcaller. you can import it from maven central.

Comment: what is "XYZ R ccommand" ? what is the error description you see?

Comment: as @Paul suggested the version was an issue.